# Snowflake builtin masking function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to mask certain data either by obfuscation or addition of a masking character.

Using traditional rpad and lpad plus replacing leading digits all have undesired outputs. SQL Server 2016 has a built in data masking function.

See mockup code:

Select mask(ssn,7,4, 'X') from dual;

input 111-11-1234
output: 111-11-XXXX

None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the "undesired outputs" are using rpad and lpad functions, but you could always create a UDF that gives you the correct reformatting of your string.  I believe that this works for what you are looking for:

```
SELECT RPAD(LEFT($1,7),LENGTH($1),'X') FROM (VALUES ('123-44-5678'));
```

Comment: I was trying to use the stuff function, but snowflake doesn't have that. This will work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Currently there is no such function in Snowflake to mask data.

But [this article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Demo-Securing-PII-Data-in-Snowflake) explains how to use roles and a mapping table to obfuscate PII data.